# Install with existing /home (encrypted)

Tags: installation, partitioning, home-directory

I have a separate `/home` partition, and I'm about to perform a reinstall (13.04 beta).

I plan to set up the same user that I have now. My current home folder is encrypted.

1. Will the installer overwrite my existing files or simply create the `/etc/passwd` entry?
2. What should I know?
3. What do I have to do? I have the encryption passphrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your /home is a completely separate partition, when you are in the install portion of 13.04 it should ask you where your /home is, you can then point to your previous /home.

The installer should not even be able to mount your /home. its encrypted, and I don't think it will ask you for permission.

Comment: For on lookers, also see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2):

I took the dive and installed anyway. I used the same user password, as with my previous install, instructed the installed to use the home partition (option called “Reinstall Ubuntu”) and everything worked flawlessly. I do seem to have a new passphrase now, but that is okay.

[image: Screenshot in Ubuntu 13.10]